# Websocket connection works in chrome but fails to connect in firefox?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, websocket, socket.io

Everything works as it should in chrome. no problems.

In Firefox i get an error : Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://domain.com

This is reproducible if you go to https://websocket.org/echo.html and replace location with wss://domain.com in chrome it works and ff it doesn't.

I'm unable to figure out why?

Using Nodejs and running on heroku, behind cloudflare.

**Edit**

So I fixed from hint by Brad.

I am using https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md for websocket.
it has an option `perMessageDeflate`.

Disabling it now make it work in FF.

Not sure What is happening but this fixed it. (am i suppose to this lib on client side as well?)

Only thing I found on MDN is this

> Gecko 8.0 Starting in Gecko 8.0 (Firefox 8.0 / Thunderbird 8.0 / SeaMonkey 2.5), the deflate-stream extension to the WebSocket protocol
>   has been disabled, since it's been deprecated from the specification
>   drafts. This resolves incompatibilities with some sites.

Comment: You're getting a `400 Bad Request` back for Firefox users.  It isn't immediately apparent as to why.  The request data between Firefox and Chrome is almost identical.  The only difference I see is Chrome has more for this header:  `Sec-Websocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits=10; server_no_context_takeover; client_no_context_takeover; server_max_window_bits=10`.

Comment: Brad post it as an answer it fixed the issue, ill accept it

Comment: Again thanks a lot

Comment: solution: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1446

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a 400 Bad Request back for Firefox users. It isn't immediately apparent as to why. The request data between Firefox and Chrome is almost identical. The only difference I see is Chrome has more for this header:

```
Sec-Websocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits=10; server_no_context_takeover; client_no_context_takeover; server_max_window_bits=10.
```

Comment: in firefox how were you able to see this, in developer tools i didn't see an option to see websocket handshake etc

Comment: @MuhammadUmer If you hit F12, you can see it in the developer tools network tab.  And, the other tool I use is Fiddler, but that had some side effects on the connection which allowed it to work a bit further.